# Need to increase width of menu bar

Tags: html, css, menubar

I'm new to coding. I made one website (ribbstech.com) using a ready made HTML template and inserted a different menu bar from some menu bar generated script. The script generated a 384px width menu bar but I wanted to make it as long as the header width which is 890px.

I tried changes in CSS but was unable to make it long. So please suggest exact changes to make it width 890px.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste in your html and css so we are able to help with your problem :)

Comment: yeah please paste your code or jsfiddle link so we can give you solution

Comment: Without show your code.. how can we help..?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try this way?

```
ul#css3menu1 {
    width: 890px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

If you want to add more menu items just copy paste, the right class for them is already fit.

Answer (score 0):

Give your ul

```
ul {width: 950px;
    background: #c1c1c1;}
```

and remove float to list and add this style:

```
ul#css3menu1 li {display: inline-block;
                 white-space: nowrap;
                 font-size: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `style.css line 30 in ul#css3menu1 a` change `padding: 10px 60px;` instead of `padding:10px;`

```
ul#css3menu1 a {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 14px Trebuchet MS;
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: #FFF 0 0 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 60px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    background-image: url("mainbk.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting your `width` to 890px

```
ul#css3menu1 {
    width: 890px;
    background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

**then if you wish to make all those menu in center**

try this

```
ul#css3menu1 li {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Style.css, Line number 13, change the ul width to following:

```
ul#css3menu1 {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 71%; /*Match the width of parent container*/
z-index: 999;
}
```

Next on line number 7 add width to li:

```
ul#css3menu1 li {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 20%; /*this width*/
}
```

Now in line number 22, add text align center to the CSS:

```
ul#css3menu1 a {
text-align: center;
}
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Got to Style.css
apply width to : `ul#css3menu1{width: 890px;}`
Apply width : to `ul#css3menu1 li{width:20% }` // as we have 5 menu and 100% of width/5 = 20%

Your menu will look like this : See screenshot [image]